# What did farmers/laborers use for boots before modern rubber existed?

Tags: clothing, industrial-revolution, labour-history

The need or usefulness to protect one's feet while doing certain duties in farming, heavy labor, and the like (such as construction with pointy things and hard edges everywhere), I am assuming has always existed - admittedly more in some pre-industrial settings than others.

But industrial (synthetic) rubber, on a wide scale, has only been available in recent times.

What was, or were, the precursors to the current, modern-day rubber-soled heavy duty boot?

Was there even as much a need to wear some heavy foot protection before the rise of modern industry anyway?

Perhaps the need for 'heavy duty' protection has increased with the rise of industrial machinery and equipment capable of chopping, dropping on or crushing your feet, and softer forms of footwear (like with thinner leather soles) or barefootedness itself was simply common among laborers of pre-rubber times?

Early Modern European (and North American settlement) communities are of particular interest.

Comment: This needs to be made more specific in terms of geography and time.

Comment: Ok - I really do mean 'everyone', as I want to know what heavy duty footwear existed (at all) before modern-day thick rubber-soled boots - but I'm not sure how I should be more specific in order to fit that goal - if you have an idea, please feel free to edit the question to put in such specificity, but I'm not sure at this point how best to do that without also restricting necessary scope.

Comment: History can't answer universally scoped questions.  This question is too broad.  Rubber soled boots evolved in the context of European and post-European colonial societies in industrialisation.  The context of Western European boot making, where industrial production was centred at the time of the development of rubber products, is the natural context.  Which leads to the natural context of European footwear after the collapse of "medieval civilisation" in the 13/14th century crises.

Comment: remeber rubber doesnt stop most of the stuff your talking about in relations to heavy duty, most heavy duty boots have metal in them to stop things like nails from going into your foot, or a blade cutting off your toes ect, rubber only stops nails of a certain length.

Comment: You need to narrow this down to at least one specific continent/country and one specific decade/century. As it is, this is way too broad.

Comment: @StevenDrennon: As Samuel Russell has already published a baseline answer, that covers the topic reasonably despite the apparent breadth of the question, I have voted to reopen.

Comment: @foregon: Pease revise or rollback my edit if I have incorrectly captured your main interest.

Comment: Check out this article: http://www.personal.utulsa.edu/~marc-carlson/shoe/DEV.HTM

Answer (score 3):

Answering in terms of western Europe after 1200CE:

**What did farmers use for boots?**

Farmers are large field agriculturalists created by the British enclosures and revolutions, and by the French and liberal revolutions in Europe.  Farmers didn't exist until very slightly before rubber shoes/boots, and were rich enough to afford leather shoes or boots and to avoid field work.<sup>1</sup>

I suspect you mean "what did peasants wear."

**What did peasants wear?**

In my judgement regarding peasants, all of the following would be used by all peasants, depending upon material availability, local culture, and wealth.  In particular, it is my view that the poorest peasants (vagabonds, waste squatters, and cottars) would have habitually not worn shoes during feudal economic crises, war, or when the level of exploitation was high.<sup>2</sup>

Nothing (source: medieval hours books, in particular Tres belles heures du Duc de Berry, https://classconnection.s3.amazonaws.com/695/flashcards/977695/jpg/labors_of_the_months_in_tres_riches_heures_du_duc_de_berry11348516007253.jpg ).

Cloth or leather shoes, with or without foot bindings / foot wraps or stockings (Hours, again)

Bare stockings

Sabots / Clogs (Wooden shoes)

**What was, or were, the precursors to the current, modern-day rubber-soled heavy duty boot?**

As a protective mud shoe, the sabot / clog.

**Was there even as much a need to wear some heavy foot protection before the rise of modern industry anyway?**

Some tools like the billhook have rounded ends to prevent damage on dropping or ground strike.  Most tools required different skills and had different safety structures: compare the serpe or serpette or pruning knife to the secateurs.

**Notes:**

These notes are a response to excellent comments on this answer.

1. While I'd dispute whether free alloders or free tenants in chief or substantially free peasant owners or renters were farmers just because they had large fields, I would certainly agree that "farming" for market began in Europe in the Netherlands to my current knowledge and was a significant practice.  I don't know enough about Dutch farm accounting in the late medieval to comment fully on class status or commodity production in terms of my theoretical apparatus.  I understate the presence of farming in the Netherlands above for two reasons: it didn't "take off" like the English or French farming practices did; it distracts from my point that farming is a historically specific economic activity not a universal term for cultivation or agriculture.
2. While the living standards of European peasants varied wildly, from freedom and plenty to dearth and slavery, peasant societies often reproduce poverty in a proportion of their community rapidly, this production of poverty being a result of the community's property behaviour without reference to exploitation by lords and priests.  As an example, the late remnants of English feudalism in the form of commons involved commoners with quarter or less commons rights who were living as squat cottars and entirely dependent upon market relations (legal or illegal) for their subsistence.  This kind of poverty has existed in European peasantries.  This kind of poverty would result in barefootedness.  I also believe that Hours books represent idealised visions of society based on the sumptuousness of the clothing depicted and would represent the broad scope of footwear, but not the rates of use.

Continued, in the matter of shoes: Dorothy Marshall (1926) *The English Poor in the Eighteenth Century* p113 adult shoes supplied on poor law 4/- stockings 1/6 per pair.(England 18th C)  Shoes in pawn 1740.  p97 late 17thC shows a rural parish child in a non-farming community going reshod year after year.  p98 shows similar children habitually starving, I doubt they'd be shod.

Samantha Williams (2011) Poverty, Gender and Life-Cycle Under the English Poor Law, 1760-1834 p31 reconstructs the family life of Lucy Townsend and William Newman, both parish dependent on and off, Shefford a rural parish late 18th C.  Newman was rateable for the poor law but in receipt of "considerable assistance" with shoes mentioned as considerable assistance.

These accounts are before the ramp-up of the poor law system with the early factory system, in one of the wealthiest societies of its era for the common person (England, 18th C), across the period, in the middle of the little ice age.  And shoes are indicated as an item delivered under sufferance.

Being without shoes might mean early death in Europe in the early modern.  Europe in the early modern was a set of societies that were quite willing to put people to death economically.

Comment: basically peasants feet were a hot mess, people lost toes, hands, eyes, lives in an instant even in industrial america, and nobody really cared. which is what gave rise to labor laws.

Comment: *Farmers* existed in The Netherlands significantly earlier than in Britain, and at least a couple of centuries before *Vulcanized* rubber was developed in 1839.

Comment: The early (read 12th century) entrepreneurs who initiated the draining and cultivation of swamps in [what is now the provinces of South and North] Holland were independent farmers, not feudal lords or peasants.

Comment: Also this, which points out the existence of *Market Gardening* in Netherlands by 1500: https://books.google.ca/books?id=RtshtNAeSvMC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=15th+century+farming+in+netherlands&source=bl&ots=_Tfdr_SFnJ&sig=DB9xVei-ygF3SUuvwA-z5arSiqs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YhIPVYqFOKn7sATW9oCwBg&ved=0CEQQ6AEwCg#v=onepage&q=15th%20century%20farming%20in%20netherlands&f=false

Comment: Your reference clearly shows peasants wearing footwear at all seasons of the year **except *high summer***, the harvest, our modern July and August; and even then some of the farm labourers are wearing footwear.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens While there's much to admire about restoring nascent Dutch agricultural capitalism to its proper place in historical narratives of capitalism, I went for the simplification (perhaps improperly).  Regarding my interpretation of the hours, I should improve this answer to indicate that the list of responses are partial.  Given my beliefs regarding the range of poverty amongst vagabonds, waste settlers / squatters and cotters I'd still stand by barefoot as an answer for some peasants as a standard year round state.  I will be modifying my answer to take account.

Comment: The revision is an improvement, but I challenge the notion that **anyone** could go barefoot in Europe north of the Alps, December to February, 1450 to 1800. This was the time of the Little Ice Age, when the canals in Netherlands froze solid, and early, every year. Frisian mantles are littered with pickled big toes of long dead relatives, frost-bitten mementos of valiant attempts to win the annual *Hans Brinker* skating race.

Comment: P.S. Those ice skates attached like a sandal, using a thong between the toes that tied over several pairs of woolen socks. You could skate with a frostbitten big toe, until it thawed.

Comment: There might be a very good question available in a late early modern European shoe debate.

Comment: Your definition of 'farmer' is perhaps a specifically British one.  It certainly doesn't match the current American usage, which encompasses anyone who cultivates land at anything over the home garden level.

Comment: The context in the question of the development of industry, modernity and modern farming techniques makes me sure in my selection of a class based definition specific to agricultures transformation into a modern industrial capitalist industry.